# Navigation Host becomes null while navigating (Android Navigation Component)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I am creating a game where the user goes through a series of 5 screens. At the last screen, the user has the choice to end the game, at which point they are taken back to the starting screen. My problems come in when a user ends the game and then starts again. While navigating through the app, the navigation host fragment cannot be found.

The first time through the app, it navigates at usual, **but the second time**, the navigation host cannot be found.

I have tried using different views to find the navigation host, and while debugging, I saw that for the fragment where it can not be found, the parent is equal to null.

This is where I navigate, in the fragments onViewCreated()

```
    viewModel.getGameUpdates().observe(activity!!, Observer { updatedGame ->
                if(updatedGame.playerList.size == 0){
                    Log.d("END","END")
                    viewModel.endGame()
                }
                adapter?.players = updatedGame.playerList

                if(updatedGame.started){
                    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_waitingFragment_to_gameFragment)
                }
            })
```

and this is the moment where the user clicks to navigate back to the first screen:

```
     btn_end_game.setOnClickListener {
                viewModel.endGame()
                timer.cancel()
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_gameFragment_to_startFragment)
            }
```

The layout for my `MainActivity` that holds the navigation host fragment is:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

I do realize that I am just adding on top of the back stack when I would rather pop back to the first fragment. I am just lost as to how the fragment is null.

The following is the `nav_graph.xml`

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/nav_graph" app:startDestination="@id/startFragment">

        <fragment android:id="@+id/startFragment" android:name="com.dangerfield.spyfall.start.StartFragment"
                  android:label="StartFragment">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_joinGameFragment" app:destination="@id/joinGameFragment"/>
            <action android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_newGameFragment" app:destination="@id/newGameFragment"/>
        </fragment>
        <fragment android:id="@+id/newGameFragment" android:name="com.dangerfield.spyfall.newGame.NewGameFragment"
                  android:label="NewGameFragment">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_newGameFragment_to_waitingFragment" app:destination="@id/waitingFragment"/>
        </fragment>
        <fragment android:id="@+id/joinGameFragment" android:name="com.dangerfield.spyfall.joinGame.JoinGameFragment"
                  android:label="JoinGameFragment">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_joinGameFragment_to_waitingFragment" app:destination="@id/waitingFragment"/>
        </fragment>
        <fragment android:id="@+id/waitingFragment" android:name="com.dangerfield.spyfall.waiting.WaitingFragment"
                  android:label="WaitingFragment">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_waitingFragment_to_gameFragment" app:destination="@id/gameFragment"/>
            <action android:id="@+id/action_waitingFragment_to_startFragment" app:destination="@id/startFragment"/>
        </fragment>
        <fragment android:id="@+id/gameFragment" android:name="com.dangerfield.spyfall.game.GameFragment"
                  android:label="GameFragment">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_gameFragment_to_startFragment" app:destination="@id/startFragment"/>
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
```

This is the message given after crash:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.ScrollView{637e4ce VFED.V... ......ID 0,0-1440,2308} does not have a NavController set`

Comment: If you're in a Fragment, you can use `NavHostFragment.findNavController(YourFragment.this)` (or just `findNavController()` if you're using the `-ktx` artifacts). Is there a reason you're using the view ones?

Comment: HI! thanks for the response, I was using the other way because I saw it in the Google documentation but I did switch to your way. However, that did not solve my problem. Instead for now I have a hack patch of checking the navController.currentDestination before navigaing. I think that with it being an observer, it was getting called more than once (after I had already navigated)

Answer (score 2):

`LiveData` remembers the current data and will automatically redeliver it when the observer becomes started again, making it inappropriate for events that trigger navigation operations: your operation to `navigate()` is going to be triggered every time your Fragment is started, making it impossible to actually pop back to that Fragment.

Note that Fragments are not destroyed while *on* the back stack. If you're changing the underlying data that your Fragment relies on while that Fragment is on the back stack, you should use the `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `this` (representing the Fragment) for your LifecycleOwner passed to `observe()` when observing in `onViewCreated()`. This ensures that you will no longer get observer callbacks once your view is destroyed (i.e., you go onto the back stack).

**`activity!!` is absolutely always wrong to use as the LifecycleOwner from within a Fragment**, since that means the observer will not be cleaned up even if the Fragment is completely destroyed (it'll only be cleaned up when the activity is destroyed).

As per the [conditional navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional), the recommended approach is to ensure that your LiveData is tracking **state** rather than events. That way, after you call `navigate()`, you can update the state to ensure that when the callback happens a second time, you don't call `navigate()` a second time. This approach is recommended over the [SingleLiveEvent approach](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150).

Comment: Thanks for the response! You are completely right about activity!! and im going to look into using the viewLifeCycleOwner instead of fragments. I had thought that using "this" would make sure the observer is only called when the fragment was in a STARTED or RESUMED state. But it seems im off by a few things here. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Would you mind if I cask: Would it be better to just navigate backwards or pop the backstack back to previous screens? I chose to pop because I did not want the back stack to continually grow.

Comment: The problem with using `this` from `onViewCreated()` is that `onViewCreated()` is called multiple times for a single Fragment instance, which means you'll have multiple observers instead of just one (it is, however, the correct thing to use from `onCreate()`, which does only happen once). It is more about the removal when the lifecycle is destroyed (`viewLifecycleOwner` -> when the view is destroyed).

Comment: oh man I wish I had you 2 days ago, hahaha. Yeha I did end up using it in onCreate() but to use viewLifeCycleOwner the view has to be created. But it seems that is best practice and that the observer should only be called in a RESUMED or STARTED state so I now an just attching them in onActivityCreated() with the viewLifeCycleOwner

Comment: In every case, the observer will only be called when the lifecycle is started. The important part is that it must be removed at the right time and that you aren't processing the same event change more than once.

Comment: okay good to know, im going to stick to using viewLifeCycle owner then if it will guarantee the life cycle awareness of my lifedata

Answer (score 1):

Even I Was facing the same issue when I used to navigate from current fragment to the next fragment, and on the back press of hardware navHost would be null, The mistake I was doing is that I had made the variable navController global where I used to instantiate like this in onCreate()

Before:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

After:

now it's working after this change

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

Dont why navController would be null if made it global??