# Fragment being destroyed and created when it is not supposed to while using android architecture components

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have a bit of a doozie. I have a game application with 3 fragments. Fragment A, fragment B, fragment C using live data and the navigatoin component from Google. When the user is done on fragment C, I use the navigation compnent to pop the back stack back to fragment A.

first problem: When I pop the back stack, the onDestroy() of that fragment is called. I was under the impression that this is not supposed to happen via this post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870210/which-method-is-being-called-after-popbackstack).

second problem: once the user is poped back to fragment A, there is an option to navigate to fragment B. Once the line is called to navigate, somehow fragment C is added to the back stack, and the view is created, causing my application to crash, as I have a listener listening to a variable in my viewModel that is shared between the fragments that is set in fragment B.

I have no idea why the fragment is getting destroyed when I pop the back stack and I have no idea why it is getting created when I try to navigate to fragment B.

I have Logged the life cycle callbacks to make sure that fragment C is being destroyed and recreated. And I have monitored the backstack of the navigation component while stepping through the app. To see fragment C being added seemingly randomly.

Considering it is code inside of an observer that crashed my app I also tried only adding the observer in the onResume() and detaching it in the onDestroy() however, when the fragment is being recreated it goes through the onResume() and just attached the observer right away

Navigation from fragment A to fragment B

```
 viewModel.addPlayer(asPlayer).addOnCompleteListener {
            Log.d("Game", "current destination before joining: "+resources.getResourceEntryName(navController.currentDestination!!.id))
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_joinGameFragment_to_waitingFragment)
        }
```

Observer getting called that leads to crash.

```
 //so this observer is not getting detached, maybe manually detach it and reattach it in on resume
        viewModel.gameExists.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { exists ->
            //someone ended the game
            var debug = navController
            if(!exists && navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.gameFragment){ endGame() }
        })
```

function that crashed

```
 fun endGame(){
        viewModel.endGame()
        Log.d("Game", "current destination before crash: "+resources.getResourceEntryName(navController.currentDestination!!.id))
        timer.cancel()
        Log.d("Game", "current destination before poping: "+resources.getResourceEntryName(navController.currentDestination!!.id))
        navController.popBackStack(R.id.startFragment, false)
        Log.d("Game", "current destination after poping: "+resources.getResourceEntryName(navController.currentDestination!!.id))

    }
```

results from log cat

```
2019-06-16 20:13:40.278 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/Game: current destination before poping:  (FRAGMENT C)
2019-06-16 20:13:40.279 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/Game: current destination after poping: (FRAGMENT A)
2019-06-16 20:13:40.279 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/View Model: game =  null
2019-06-16 20:13:40.299 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/GAME: ON DESTROY
2019-06-16 20:13:40.315 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/View Model: game =  null
2019-06-16 20:14:05.289 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/Game: current destination before joining: (FRAGMENT A)
2019-06-16 20:14:05.316 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/Game: on Create
2019-06-16 20:14:05.317 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/Game: onCreateView
2019-06-16 20:14:05.353 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/GAME: ON RESUME
2019-06-16 20:14:05.353 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall D/Game: current destination before crash: (FRAGMENT C)
019-06-16 20:14:05.359 13021-13021/com.dangerfield.spyfall E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dangerfield.spyfall, PID: 13021
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property timer has not been initialized
        at com.dangerfield.spyfall.game.GameFragment.endGame(GameFragment.kt:158)
```

(game fragment is fragment C)

Any help/ direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: Fragments are always destroyed when they are popped off the back stack.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks for your response man. Would you mind pointing me in the direction of some documentation that would help me learn about that behavior? I could not find that anywhere. Also even with the fragment getting destroyed, it does not make sense for it to get added to the back stack again and to be resumed without making it.

Comment: See [my answer on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56623890/1676363). You need to fix your `observe()` calls.